# Firestore security rules when updating database from a script that doesn't have auth

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am using these Firestore security rules:

```
// Allow read/write access on all documents to any user signed in to the application
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is, for a feature in my react-native app, a callback is executed (to share a transaction id) and the app exits to the browser to handle the callback. In the callback script on my server, I have some code like this:

```
        fetch(url, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
            }
        }).then(response => {

          if (response.ok) {
            response.json().then(json => {

                if(json.data == "Manual sale") {
                    alert("Manual sale complete! Return to Fairstarter!");
                    return;
                }

                var quant = 0;
                var itemsRef = db.collection('items');
                var query = itemsRef.where('barcode', '==', String(json.data)).get()
                    .then(snapshot => {

                      snapshot.forEach(doc => {

                          ....

                          //UPDATE THAT IS LOCKED OUT BY PERMISSIONS
                          itemsRef.doc(doc.id).update({
                             [Object.keys(doc.data())[0]]]: {
                                quantity: newVal
                             }
                          })
```

The problem is, in the above block I try to update the database, but since I am not coming from something that has an existing firebase user for auth, I get denied by firebase because of permissions.

How do I keep the database secure while still allowing the callback script to update the database?

Comment: Please don't just slap on some general looking tags. Make sure you read the tag info and get the correct tags for your question. For example the [tag:firebase-database] tag is for the realtime database and not firestore.

Comment: javascript makes sense though, a potential solution might require some sort of javascript anonymous auth...just a guess obviously since i havent been able to find the answer yet

Answer (score 0):

Using firebase anonymous sign in works, I put this at the top of my script after firebase gets configured:

```
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
      if (user) {
        // User is signed in.
        var isAnonymous = user.isAnonymous;
        //alert(user.uid);
        // ...
      } else {
        // User is signed out.
        // ...
      }
      // ...
    });

    firebase.auth().signInAnonymously().catch(function(error) {
          // Handle Errors here.
          var errorCode = error.code;
          var errorMessage = error.message;
          // ...
          alert(errorMessage);
    });
```

Don't forget to enable anonymous auth in your firebase project settings.